# how to render ejs file with mongoose data?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

I'm trying to create a dynamic page where the variable in the URL will be taken and the data will be searched in mongodb and the matched data along with its collection will be rendered in an ejs page. I'm new to express and mongoose. I've written this code.

```
app.get("/product/:data",function(req,res){
    var dataCopy = res.params.data;
    if(dataCopy =="dog")//dog catagory
    {
    return Product.findOne({catagory : "Dog"},function(err,products)
        {
          if(err)
            {
            console.log(err);
            }else
            {
         res.render("product", {products : products});   
            }
        });
    }
    else if(dataCopy=="cat")//cat catagory
    {
     Product.findOne({catagory : "Cat"},function(err,products)
        {
          if(err)
            {
            console.log(err);
            }else
            {
         res.render("product",{products : products});   
            }
        });
    }else {
res.redirect("/home"); 
   }
});
```

the code is able to collect the collection of matched query data from the DB but is able to render the data in basic html page without css & js. but when i'm rendering the same page in a specific route eg. (/product/dog), the page is rendering with css and js.
Help me with a solution.

Comment: **the code is able to collect the collection of matched query data from the DB but is able to render the data in basic html page without css & js. but when i'm rendering the same page in a specific route eg. (/product/dog), the page is rendering with css and js.** What did you mean by that?

Comment: The Product.findOne({catagory:"Dog"}, function (req,res)  // it is searching the dog catagory and the whole collection is called by the "products" name. But when I'm rendering the ejs page, the css & js in that page are not working. But when I've rendered the same ejs file in other route, all the css & js are working perfectly fine.

Comment: css and js scripts work no matter what, irrespective of route it is rendered from. I hope you have put css and jss scripts in public or views folder  whichever you've set like this `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

Comment: Can you show the ejs templates you are referring to?  Also, I don't think you should have a `return` statement in your `app.get` route.